# R function which generates random sequences of heads and tails for any value of n

Tags: r

I am new to `R` hence asking here (haven't been able to find very helpful tutorials for simulation that are detailed.)

The problem statement is this

(a) Write a `R` function which generates random sequences of heads and tails for any value of n.

I did the following:

```r
n <- 20                #no of trials
y <- NULL              #initializing a vector of NULL values   
for (i in 1:n) {
  x <- runif(1)        #random uniform
  if (x < 0.5) {       #if condition for assigning heads / tails
    y[i] <- 'H'
  } else {
    y[i] <- 'T'
  }
}

y                      #print the vector storing the heads and tails.
```

I need a `R` code for the above problem. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like homework, too. Have a look at the  `? sample` for part 1, have a look at the `?rle` for part 2 and for part 3 you'll need to do some statistical derivations, determining the probability distribution of the longest sequence, or so.

Comment: rbinom will simulate bernoulli random variable with x <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)

Answer (score 2):

rbinom will simulate bernoulli random variable with

```
x <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)
```

Comment: `sample(c("H", "T"), n, replace = T)` will do the same.

Comment: Its generating an output of int [1:20] 0011101100... But i need an output like HHTHTTHHHHTTTHHTTTTH